# merge mail: only integer columns are shown, others are empty

Tags: mysql, ms-word, mailmerge, col

I am using a mySql Database as datasource for word merge mail.

In the recipient table I have issues with the "string" columns.
They are all empty but the columns with numbers are shown.

vba:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource "", connection:=connection, SQLStatement:=query
```

Merge Mail Table: Only integer colomn values are existing

[image]

Microsoft Query Table: All colomn values are existing

[image]

Is there a cast between the merge mail table and the microsoft query table
which goes wrong ?

### update

If I manually add the data source with the wizard,
the data is listed correctly,

<s>There seems to be a problem with the vba code
maybe I missed some option ?</s>

There was a problem with the character encoding.

thanks in advice

Comment: dude we know nothing about your DB, your query, your settings or how data is pulled into your application. provide more Information please

Comment: its not a problem with the query or database

Comment: well then if the actual table has those fields blank it would obviously result in those fields giving blank when queried. On other hand if you want to change the field type of a column in a table you will need to use "alter" command. And if you want to update query then you will have to  post the actual query so that anyone can give suggestions.

Comment: so can you explain why the int fields are shown, the varchar strings not. I don't see an issue in the query since it is shown correctly in the microsoft query but false in the merge field table

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I used the `MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver` for the DSN.

Now after using the `MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver` the colomn values are now existing and shown in the mail merge fields.